# difference between COM port and SATA

Tags: port, sata

can somebody please explain why can't I say that SATA is a COM port, `SATA is a serial port` and COM port is a `general name` for serial ports, am I wrong? thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

COM ports are the common name for EIA-232 ports (aka RS-232), i.e. ports where only the lower levels of communication are defined: physical (mechanical and electrical) and data link.

For SATA these are different, and SATA defines also network and transport layers, which means packaging and error detection/correction. You can run a protocol on CMO ports which do this too, but they're not part of the COM specification itself.

Comment: but I thougt that UART is the common name for RS-232, am I wrong?

Comment: @geek - UART specifies only the format start/data/stop bits, and the bit rate. EIA-232 also specifies electrical levels and the connector. You can perfectly connect two microcontrollers via their UARTs without caring about EIA-232 levels or using a cable/connectors.

Comment: The [UART][1] is an _universal asynchronous receiver/ transmitter_. For a simple microcomputer environment is it the _serial controller_ - which the CPU can off-load the slow task of sending and receiving serial data transfers, which optionally includes a FIFO buffer, so that the CPU is can be interrupted less frequently (for the higher speed data transfer from the CPU to the UART), thus the CPU is not slowed down while the UART is tasked with send/receiving serial data. For x86 PCs, the National Semiconductor's 8250 and 16550 series.  [1] http://goo.gl/pyhtq

Comment: Yes, a UART is a peripheral chip or functional block, not a protocol or interface specification... though in everyday discussion it's often used to imply the data format used by these chips.

Comment: Nowadays, COM port is the common name for both EIA-232 ports and things that, from a software perspective, pretend to be EIA-232 ports.  Something like an FTDI-based interface cable with logic-level outputs would be considered a COM port even though it's not EIA-232.

Answer (score 5):

The "COM" port is the name given to an RS-232 port in DOS (and continued into windows).  It is specific to that type of port on that operating system.  As far as I am aware no other operating system uses the name "COM" port.  Unix & Linux refer to them as "Serial TTY ports".

> COM is the original, yet still common, name of the serial port interface on IBM PC-compatible computers. It might not only refer to physical ports, but also to virtual ports, such as ports created by bluetooth or USB-to-Serial adapters.
>
> ***- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_%28hardware_interface%29)***

SATA, while yes it is a "serial protocol" is not a COM port and has nothing to do with COM or RS-232.  Line signaling levels are completely different, the data contained within the bit-stream is formed differently, etc.

> Serial ATA (SATA or Serial Advanced Technology Attachment) is a computer bus interface for connecting host bus adapters to mass storage devices such as hard disk drives and optical drives. Serial ATA was designed to replace the older ATA (AT Attachment) standard (also known as EIDE), offering several advantages over the older parallel ATA (PATA) interface: reduced cable-bulk and cost (7 conductors versus 40), native hot swapping, faster data transfer through higher signalling rates, and more efficient transfer through an (optional) I/O queuing protocol.
>
> ***- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SATA)***

Trying to compare the two is like trying to compare a parallel printer port with a parallel IDE connector.  While they are both parallel, they are completely different in the way they operate and the signals that are passed through them.

While you're about it, you may as well say that USB is the same as COM and SATA, and why not include DVI in that as well?  Or Ethernet?  They're all "serial protocols" in that they transmit one bit after another, but they are all so different to each other in so many ways that they just cannot be compared to each other in a sensible manner.

Comment: Copy and paste from Wikipedia. Wouldn't OP have looked there already?

Comment: Well, judging by the question, I'd say a resounding "NO".

Comment: Yes, but that's because I said "wouldn't", where I meant "couldn't"! Then the answer would be a resounding YES ;-). What I meant is that there's little added value in copying information that already is available. It would be different if it were hidden in some obscure paper with a circulation of 100. If you know what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is, "COM port" is not a general name for a serial port. It's a name specifically for PC serial ports. Even though serial data transfer takes place in both COM and SATA connections, the two are completely incompatible, so it's just incorrect to call a SATA connection a COM port.